# How to update a record in Kohana 3.0

Tags: kohana-3, kohana-orm

I want to update a record in a table. I'm using Kohana 3.0 and ORM. My code is as follows -

```
$photo_sel =  $this->where('id','=',$this_photo_id)
                   ->where('user_id','=',$user_id)
                   ->where('is_logo','=','0')->find();

        if ($photo_sel->loaded()) {     
             $this->photo_file_name = $photo;                
              parent::save();
        }
```

But every time the first record is updated. Instead I want to  select and update the record with $this_photo_id.

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to update the selected record, modify and save this record only:

```
$photo_sel =  $this->where('id','=',$this_photo_id)
                   ->where('user_id','=',$user_id)
                   ->where('is_logo','=','0')->find();

if ($photo_sel->loaded()) {     
     $photo_sel->photo_file_name = $photo;                
     $photo_sel->save();
}
```